# SQL create table primary key and foreign key syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm creating a MySQL database for homework, and running into syntax error #1005 in phpmyadmin. I think it has something to do with the foreign keys but if w3schools has is right my syntax should be good.

Here's the SQL statements;

```
create table if not exists customers
(
    id int not null auto_increment, 
    cust_gname varchar(20) not null, 
    cust_fname varchar(30) not null, 
    cust_street varchar(30) not null, 
    cust_suburb varchar(30) not null, 
    cust_state varchar(6) not null, 
    cust_postcode varchar(4) not null, 
    cust_email varchar(50) not null, 
    cust_phone varchar(12), 
    cust_mobile varchar(12), 
    cust_user_id int, 
    foreign key (cust_user_id) references users(id),
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists ingredients
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(30) not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists recipes
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(30) not null, 
    recipes_menu_id int,
    foreign key (recipes_menu_id) references menus(id)
    image varchar(30),
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists ingredients_recipes
(
    id int, 
    ingredients_recipes_ingredient_id int,
    foreign key (ingredients_recipes_ingredient_id) references ingredients(id), 
    ingredients_recipes_recipe_id int,
    foreign key (ingredients_recipes_recipe_id) references recipes(id),
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists menus
(
    id int, 
    description varchar(30) not null, 
    menus_restaurant_id int, 
    foreign key (menus_restaurant_id) references restaurants(id),
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists restaurants
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(30) not null, 
    address1 varchar(30) not null, 
    address 2 varchar(30), 
    suburb varchar(30) not null, 
    state varchar(10) not null, 
    postcode varchar(4) not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists customers_ingredients
(
    id int, 
    customers_ingredients_customer_id int,
    foreign key (customers_ingredients_customer_id) references customers(id), 
    customers_ingredients_ingredient_id int, 
    foreign key (customers_ingredients_ingredient_id) references ingredients(id),
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists users
(
    id int, 
    username varchar(40) not null, 
    password varchar(50) not null, 
    group_id int,
    created DATETIME, 
    modified DATETIME,
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists groups
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(10) not null, 
    created DATETIME, 
    modified DATETIME,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: the `recipes` table isn't right, missing a `,`...

Comment: w3schools is not a good place to learn SQL. Their website is full of errors. The DBMS manual is a much better place to find the correct syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're creating a table with a foreign key reference, the table to which it refers must already exist. You're creating a `customers` table at the start of the script which refers to the `users` table which isn't created until near the end. There are other examples in the script too.

You need either to create the tables in the right order, or use `set foreign_key_checks = 0;` at the top to disable this requirement. Make sure you `set foreign_key_checks = 1` at the end once all your tables are created.

Note: there may be other syntax errors in your script - I haven't checked it all.

Comment: brilliant i didn't know that. you'd think they'd mention that on w3schools on the foreign key page...